# Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\<username>\.aws\credentials'

Tags: javascript, node.js, runtime-error, scanning, amazon-textract

node index.js scan helloworld is giving the above error
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users<username>.aws\credentials'
the credentials.txt is there in the above folder path.
and the contents are in place already.this issue is fixed but after that am getting the below error;
Error: EISDIR: illegal operation on a directory, read

Please assist.

Comment: this error is coming up when am trying to scan a pdf using amazon textract and node js. am also trying node index.js scan <pdffilename>, it is throwing the same error, the pdf is in the current directory where am running the node scan

Comment: Can anyone assist or suggest a solution..!!

Comment: This looks liek a permission issue. Move your credentials file somewhere else where you have right to read them without using admin